# Do the two top level elements conflict in xml stylesheet?

Tags: xml, xslt, stylesheet

in a xml stylesheet,"strip-space" select all elements(elements="*"),but "preserve-space" selects part of elements, does the two root elements of stylesheet conflict with each other?

how will the elements belong to "strip-space" and "preserve-space" be parsed? 
such as "abbrev","abbrev_journal_title"?

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Space is preserved in all elements allowing #PCDATA -->
  <xsl:preserve-space
    elements="abbrev abbrev-journal-title access-date addr-line aff 
              alt-text alt-title article-id article-title attrib 
              award-id bold chapter-title chem-struct collab comment 
              compound-kwd-part conf-acronym conf-date conf-loc conf-name 
              conf-num conf-sponsor conf-theme copyright-holder 
              copyright-statement copyright-year corresp country 
              date-in-citation day def-head degrees disp-formula 
              edition elocation-id email etal ext-link fax fpage 
              funding-source funding-statement given-names glyph-data gov 
              inline-formula inline-supplementary-material institution 
              isbn issn issue issue-id issue-part issue-sponsor 
              issue-title italic journal-id journal-subtitle 
              journal-title kwd label license-p long-desc lpage 
              meta-name meta-value mixed-citation monospace month 
              named-content object-id on-behalf-of overline p 
              page-range part-title patent phone prefix preformat 
              price principal-award-recipient principal-investigator 
              product pub-id publisher-loc publisher-name 
              related-article related-object role roman sans-serif 
              sc season self-uri series series-text series-title 
              sig sig-block size source speaker std strike 
              string-conf string-date string-name styled-content sub 
              subject subtitle suffix sup supplement surname target 
              td term term-head tex-math textual-form th time-stamp 
              title trans-source trans-subtitle trans-title underline 
              unstructured-kwd-group uri verse-line volume volume-id 
              volume-series x xref year 

              mml:annotation mml:ci mml:cn mml:csymbol mml:mi mml:mn 
              mml:mo mml:ms mml:mtext"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

## from W3C

For source documents, the set of `whitespace-preserving` element names is specified by `xsl:strip-space` and `xsl:preserve-space` top-level elements. These elements each have an elements attribute whose value is a whitespace-separated list of NameTests. Initially, the set of whitespace-preserving element names contains all element names. If an element name matches a `NameTest` in an `xsl:strip-space` element, then it is removed from the set of whitespace-preserving element names. If an element name matches a NameTest in an `xsl:preserve-space` element, then it is added to the set of whitespace-preserving element names. An element matches a NameTest if and only if the NameTest would be true for the element as an `XPath node test`. Conflicts between matches to `xsl:strip-space` and `xsl:preserve-space` elements are resolved the same way as conflicts between template rules (see [**5.5 Conflict Resolution for Template Rules**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#conflict)).

Answer (score 1):

> Do the two top level elements conflict in xml stylesheet?

**Yes, and the [W3 XSLT Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#strip) prescribes a strict way of resolving those conflicts**:

> *Conflicts between matches to xsl:strip-space and xsl:preserve-space elements are resolved the same way as conflicts between template rules
>   (see [[5.5 Conflict Resolution for Template Rules]](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#conflict)). Thus, the
>   applicable match for a particular element name is determined as
>   follows*:
>
> - *First, any match with lower import precedence than another match is ignored*.
> - *Next, any match with a NameTest that has a lower default priority than the default priority of the NameTest of another match is
>     ignored*.
>
> *It is an error if this leaves more than one match. An XSLT processor may signal the error; if it does not signal the error, it must recover
>   by choosing, from amongst the matches that are left, the one that
>   occurs last in the stylesheet*.

o, in simple words, the one of the two conflicting rules (`xsl:strip-space` and `xsl:preserve-space`) that comes last for a given name, wins or the XSLT processor gives an error message.

**Do note, however, that there is no conflict** between:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

and

```
<xsl:preserve-space elements="someName"/>
```

because any name is more specific than `*` and thus has higher precedence.

**Therefore, in this specific example, the white-space only text nodes - children of all elements with names in `xsl:preserve-space` will be preserved** -- regardless of the order of `xsl:strip-space elements="*"` `xsl:preserve-space elements="{list-of-names}"`, because a name is more specific than `*`.

Comment: No, that's wrong. If you have a "*" rule and one mentioning the name explicitly, the latter wins, regardless of the order.

Comment: Before your edit, it was at least misleading. Now it is ok, I think.

Answer (score 0):

As you intend, probably: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_preserve-space.asp
or here: http://xmlplease.com/whitespace

All whitespace nodes not appearing in your preserve-space list will be deleted, i.e.

```
<someexample>    </someexample>
```

will be treated as if it were

```
<someexample />
```

Since your list is more specific than "*", it has precendence, see the link in the other post.